# How to use Dropdown list inside kendo grid mvvm

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo mvvm grid in that how to keep dropdown list when it is on editable mode 
I am new to using this kendo and mvvm concepts please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
    var grid = $("#example div[data-role='grid']").data("kendoGrid");       
    $.each(grid.columns, function (idx, column) {
        if (column.field == "CourseName") 
            column.editor = viewModel.xx;       
    });

   xxx: function name(container, options) {
            $('<input id="ddl" data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')                
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/controller/method",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                autoBind: false,
                index: -1
            });
        }
```